# Sum each element of a row from two files

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write shell script in which each row's column element from file1 and file2 are added.

`file1`:

```
A 10 12 13 14
B 2 5 6 10
C 1
```

`file2`:

```
A 11 13 11 15
B 3 1 1 1
C 2
```

`output`:

```
A 22 25 24 29
B 5 6 7 11
C 3
```

I have tried to write this, but it seems very chaotic.
So I'd like to get some help to make it better!

```
awk '{getline v < "file1"; split( v, a ); 
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
            {print a[1], a[i]+ $i}
        }' file2 > temp

awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}
    END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]
    }' temp > out
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## file1

```
A 10 12 13 14
B 2 5 6 10
C 1
```

## file2

```
A 11 13 11 15
B 3 1 1 1
C 2
```

## Programme

```
cat file1 file2 | cut -d" " -f1 | sort -u | while read i
do
  line1="`grep ^$i file1 | sed -e "s/  */ /g" | cut -d" " -f2-` "
  line2="`grep ^$i file2 | sed -e "s/  */ /g" | cut -d" " -f2-` "
  (
  echo $i
  while [ "${line1}${line2}" != "" ]
  do
    v1=0`echo "$line1" | cut -d" " -f1`
    v2=0`echo "$line2" | cut -d" " -f1`
    line1="`echo "$line1" | cut -d" " -f2-`"
    line2="`echo "$line2" | cut -d" " -f2-`"
    echo `expr $v1 + $v2`
  done
  ) | xargs
done > file3
```

## file3

```
A 21 25 24 29
B 5 6 7 11
C 3
```

This solution remains valid if the number of column or lines are not identical, the missing values are considered 0

```
#file1
A 10 12 13 14
B 2 5 6
C 1 10
D 1 1

#file2
A 11 13 11 15
B 3 1 1 1 5
C 2
F 3 3

#file3
A 21 25 24 29
B 5 6 7 1 5
C 3 10
D 1 1
F 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks so much. . .. It is a very elegant solution! !!